# Invariant mass spectrum to a transverse momentum distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, higgs

For the decay of the Higgs boson in 2 photons having the following invariant mass formula:

$$M = 2E_{1}E_{2}(1 - \cos \theta)$$

How can I go from an invariant mass spectrum distribution to a transverse momentum distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting 
$$\theta := \theta_1 + \theta_2$$,

the momentum of the Higgs boson (candidate) with respect to the lab
$$ \| \textbf p_{lab}[~H~] \| = \| \textbf p_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] \| ~\text{Cos}[~\theta_1~] + \| \textbf p_{lab}[~\gamma_2~] \| ~\text{Cos}[~\theta_2~] = (E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] ~ \text{Cos}[~\theta_1~] + E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~] ~ \text{Cos}[~\theta_2~]) / 2,  $$

the transverse momentum magnitude of both photons equally as
$$ \| \textbf p_{lab}^{trans~H}[~\gamma_1~] \| = \| \textbf p_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] \| ~\text{Sin}[~\theta_1~] = \| \textbf p_{lab}^{trans~H}[~\gamma_2~] \| = \| \textbf p_{lab}[~\gamma_2~] \| ~ \text{Sin}[~\theta_2~] = E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] ~ \text{Sin}[~\theta_1~] / c = E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~] ~ \text{Sin}[~\theta_2~] / c $$

and with

$$\sqrt{ (M~c^2)^2 + (\| \textbf p_{lab}[~H~] \| c)^2 } = E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] + E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~]$$

I get, first of all, the invariant mass (of the Higgs boson (candidate)) as

$$M^2 = 2~E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~]~E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~]~(1 - \text{Cos}[~\theta~]) / c^4,$$

in other words: in the formula as presently stated in the question the $M$ seems to be missing a square;

and I get the "*transverse momentum*" (magnitude) in terms of $M$ and the two photon energies as

$$\| \textbf p_{lab}^{trans~H}[~\gamma_1~] \| = \| \textbf p_{lab}^{trans~H}[~\gamma_2~] \| = \frac{M~c}{2}~\sqrt{ \frac{4~E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~]~E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~] - M^2~c^4}{(E_{lab}[~\gamma_1~] + E_{lab}[~\gamma_2~])^2 - M^2~c^4}}.$$

Comment: Thank you ! But I don't really see how you get the last formula ?

Comment: Samuel: "_Thank you !_" -- You're welcome. "_But I don't really see how you get the last formula ?_" -- Actually, I typed some equivalent of the second, third, and fourth equation of my answer in my equation solver program, solving for $\|\mathbf p_{lab}^{trans~H}[~\gamma~]\|$ (which is the same value for both photons), along with $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. (The version history of my answer shows that I also had made some mistakes in the process.) Now your question made me think again ... So I've simplified and checked:`Solve[ M^2 + (Sqrt[ e^2 - t^2 ] + Sqrt[ f^2 - t^2 ])^2 == (e + f)^2, t ]`.